# "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" taking time for load than push

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pushviewcontroller

I have issue to push one view to other view & also find out bug on code but i have tried to find out solution.see the code below

```
print("<< 1st Execution >>")
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as! view2
print("<< 2st Execution  >>")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,animated: true)
```

in running time  `print("<< 1st Execution >>")` print immediately but `print("<< 2st Execution  >>")` taking time because of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Comment: Does your `viewDidLoad` of `view2` contains any Synchronous Tasks ?

Comment: sir, i have already try with viewDidLoad & viewWillAppare but didn't work

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  When I time profile it, my call to `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:` clocks at about 1-2 second/s (which is unacceptable for an app).

Answer (score 0):

Is view2 UIViewController??

You must choose a right storyboard.
if view2 would be a name of UIViewController, you maybe try it by this way.

let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as! view2